# Can you move values from an Arc<Mutex<Vec>> to a &mut Vec without the cost of transferring them?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to move items from an `Arc<Mutex<T>>` (`T` is a `Vec` or a `HashMap`, but I guess any type) to an `&mut T` without the computational cost of transferring the items via draining/adding them between the types?

For instance:

```rust
fn main() {
  let mut items = Vec::<usize>::new();
  
  {
    let mut items_ref = &mut items;
    let mut items_protec = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::<usize>::new()));

    {
      // do stuff to items_protec
    }

    // Move items to ref
    // Does the compiler optimize this away?
    let mut items_unprotec = items_protec.lock().unwrap();
    while let Some(item) in items_unprotec.pop() {
      items_ref.push(item);
    }
  }

  for item in &items {
    println!("{}", item);
  }
}
```

Would the compiler optimize away the loop that transfers the values?

Comment: Why would the compiler optimize it away? What _can_ it optimize away here? You may be able to have `Vec` make more efficient reallocations using `items_ref.extend(items_unprotec.drain(..).rev())` though.

Comment: I have tried putting the `&mut T` into the Arc<Mutex<&mut T>> then taking it out at the end - but that's not permitted due to lifetimes. I know I can move `T` into the closure then return it after with a new assignment but I am trying to avoid that if possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `std::mem::take` to take the entire `Vec` out of `items_protec` and assign it to `items_ref` leaving a default `Vec` in its place:

```
*items_ref = std::mem::take(&mut *items_protec.lock().unwrap());
```

Since this just transfers ownership, it does not move the underlying objects and uses the original allocation. This same strategy will work for any type that you want to take *completely* out of the `Mutex` (if it implements `Default`).

It is unlikely the compiler could or would optimize the original loop to this simpler method.

Comment: I think it’s important to clarify in “Since this just transfers ownership, it does not move the underlying objects and uses the original allocation. This same strategy will work for any type that you want to take completely out of the `Mutex` (if it implements `Default`).” that taking out a big array would be copied at a high cost, for example, since it doesn’t have another level of indirection like `Vec`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that nobody else holds a reference to the `Arc` when you want to retrieve the data (i.e. if its reference count is 1), then you can do the following to take the data out of the `Arc` and `Mutex`:

```
let m = Arc::into_inner (items_protec).unwrap();
let items = m.into_inner().unwrap();
```